# Android avd on mac when starting emulator device unknown option -scale

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device

When I use default settings to emulate an Android device (ex: Nexus 5) it boots up and works just fine, but I am trying to fine tune a new virtual device to be more true with device resolution, but no luck. When I attempt to change the scale to anything other than AUTO (ex: 1dp = 2px on screen, 2dp = 1px on screen, etc.) it always fails to launch with the following message.

"Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: unknown option: -scale, please use -help for a list of valid options"

**Note: I am simply creating a new virtual device via the AVD Manager GUI.

I am not sure where to go with this message. I am using Android 2.0 Beta and on Mac OS X El Capitan.

Thank you!